# Get 'this' from function call defined by Object.defineProperties()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a function to the `__proto__` of `Object` using JavaScript.

Apparently, jQuery has some problems when defining prototype functions as `Object.prototype.myFunc = function() {};` so the best workaround I found was using `Object.defineProperties()` so I could set `enumerable` to `false`, thus working with jQuery.

I'm trying to use the following code

```js
Object.defineProperties(Object.prototype, {
    length: {
        value: (function () {
            return Object.keys(this).length;
        })(),
        enumerable: false
    }
});
```

But when using `Objects.defineProperties()` the `this` keyword doesn't work the same way as on

```js
Object.prototype.myFunc = function() {
    return Object.keys(this).length;
};
```

How can I have the same result of the code above but using `Object.defineProperties()` or some similar workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing the `value` property by a `get()`?

You can replace:

```
value: (function () {
    return Object.keys(this).length;
})(),
```

with:

```
get() {
    return Object.keys(this).length;
},
```

```js
Object.defineProperties(Object.prototype, {
  length: {
    get() {
      return Object.keys(this).length;
    },
    enumerable: false,
  }
});

const obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
};

const obj2 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5,
};


console.log('obj1.length:', obj1.length);
console.log('obj2.length:', obj2.length);
```